# convert-multiple-files npm package not working on elastic beanstalk amazon Linux 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, amazon-linux-2

After a successful deployment, when I run the my file conversion script as mentioned in the docs the  conversion fails. my conversion script.

> the script runs perfectly in local windows 10 machine and ubuntu 20.04 lts

```js
const { convertWordFiles } = require("convert-multiple-files");
const path = require("path");

async function test() {
  try {
    const infoOutput = await convertWordFiles(
      path.resolve(__dirname, `../../temp/test02.docx`),
      "pdf",
      path.resolve(__dirname, `../../temp`)
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

test();
```

**The Error**  I got was  this

```
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/utils/instdir/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libxslt.so.1: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: Error: Error converting the file
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:68:19
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at step (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:33:23)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at Object.next (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:14:53)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:8:71
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at new WrappedPromise (/var/app/current/node_modules/async-listener/es6-wrapped-promise.js:13:18)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at __awaiter (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:4:12)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at convertWordFiles (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:44:75)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at FileHandlerService.preparePreview (/var/app/current/src/services/fileHandler.js:67:9)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at prepareDocumentPreview (/var/app/current/src/subprocess/fileConverter.js:20:60)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at async process.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/src/subprocess/fileConverter.js:27:16)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: Error: Error converting the file
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:68:19
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at step (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:33:23)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at Object.next (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:14:53)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:8:71
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at new WrappedPromise (/var/app/current/node_modules/async-listener/es6-wrapped-promise.js:13:18)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at __awaiter (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:4:12)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at convertWordFiles (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:44:75)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at FileHandlerService.preparePreview (/var/app/current/src/services/fileHandler.js:67:9)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at prepareDocumentPreview (/var/app/current/src/subprocess/fileConverter.js:20:60)
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at async process.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/src/subprocess/fileConverter.js:27:16) null
```

After that I had to install the two packages `libxslt` and `libSM` and this portions was not there anymore

```
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/utils/instdir/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libxslt.so.1: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

which means library did load.

but this time i got error without any clue, that came from the following line

```
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: Error: Error converting the file
Jul  5 11:30:02 web: at /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:68:19
```

I did put a console log in `convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:68` and I got the following output

```
Error: Command failed: /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/utils/instdir/program/soffice.bin --headless --norestore --invisible --nodefault --nofirststartwizard --nolockcheck --nologo --convert-to pdf --outdir /var/app/current/temp '/var/app/current/temp/test02.docx'
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:652:15)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:61:31
    at step (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:14:53)       
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:4:12)
    at convertWordFiles (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:44:75)  
    at test (/var/app/current/src/services/converter.js:6:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/src/services/converter.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  status: 77,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, <Buffer >, <Buffer > ],
  pid: 4311,
  stdout: <Buffer >,
  stderr: <Buffer >
}
Error: Error converting the file
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:69:19
    at step (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:14:53)       
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:4:12)
    at convertWordFiles (/var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/lib/index.js:44:75)  
    at test (/var/app/current/src/services/converter.js:6:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/src/services/converter.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

is there any obvious reason for the problem or am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 1):

So after a bit of debugging I figured out that it was actually a permission issue and I ended up writing a `config` file for my elastic beanstalk environment, the contents of the file are given bellow

```
commands:
    01-install_dependencies:
        command: sudo yum install libxslt libSM
        cwd: /home/ec2-user
    02-update_cache:
        command: sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
        cwd: /home/ec2-user
    03-provide_write_permission_to_convert_multiple_files_lib:
        command: sudo chmod -R 777 /var/app/current/node_modules/convert-multiple-files/*
        cwd: /home/ec2-user
```